# Can you remove items from a list by non-numeric character in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have list that may update in the future, but I do not want to print out all of the results. I want to limit the list that is printed to items that do not include the "+" sign or a ".", leaving only the folders whose names I desire.

```
myList = ['+Map_Design', 'for_pl', 'land_comm', 'FILE LIST - Shortcut (2).lnk', 
          'SiteLocatorMap.mxd', 'Thumbs.db']
```

I have tried using...

```
[x for x in myList if not '.' in x]
```

and

```
[x for x in myList if not . in x]
```

with no luck. Is this an issue with the characters that I'm trying to remove (.,+) or am I using the wrong code.

What I'm looking for would be a list that includes only ['for_pl', 'land_comm'] in this example.

Comment: When I do `print [x for x in myList if not '.' in x]`, I get `['+Map_Design', 'for_pl', 'land_comm']`, which is indeed the elements of the list that don't contain a period. Is that not what you're getting?

Comment: Down voters are so rude...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your full code looks like

```
myList = ['+Map_Design', 'for_pl', 'land_comm', 'FILE LIST - Shortcut (2).lnk', 'SiteLocatorMap.mxd', 'Thumbs.db']
[x for x in myList if not '.' in x]
[x for x in myList if not '+' in x]
print myList
```

By themselves, list comprehensions don't modify the thing you're iterating over. Try assigning the result back to `myList`

```
myList = ['+Map_Design', 'for_pl', 'land_comm', 'FILE LIST - Shortcut (2).lnk', 'SiteLocatorMap.mxd', 'Thumbs.db']
myList = [x for x in myList if not '.' in x]
myList = [x for x in myList if not '+' in x]
print myList
```

Result:

```
['for_pl', 'land_comm']
```

---

Bonus style tip: `'.' not in x` is more idiomatic than `not '.' in x`.

Comment: Thank you I had never used the x in x and therefore did not recognize that you had to assign the operation to a list.

Comment: I had an issue using the [x in x] function within pythonWin when using the "Step Over" function in the debugger. The process would just freeze, but would work when I ran the script as a whole.